# Using data stored in cache/storage instead of database

Tags: laravel

I was thinking about using cache/storage to store source for api routes which doesnt update that much. I mean i would like to update stored data every one minute (example) and my routes will use that data as source instead of database as source. It will make less database queries. Im I thinking in good way? How to achieve that in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an instance of [memcached](https://memcached.org/) which is supported by Laravel. The Laravel caching [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache) is a good place to start learning how to setup a cache driver for memcached. Once setup, your logic could look something like this:

```
if (Cache::has('key')) {
    //your key exists in the cache. get it.
    $value = Cache::get('key');

    //and use it
    useMyValue($value);
}
else
{
    //the cache does not contain the key you are looking for
    //you can get it from the DB and cache it.
    //the next time your function runs it will get the value from cache instead
    //of reading from the db
    $value = Cache::get('key', function () {
        return DB::table(...)->get();
    });
    //and use your value now like normal
    useMyValue()
}
```

Comment: `$value = Cache::remember('my-api-response', 1, function() { return DB::table(...)->get(); })` will do the same in a cleaner way.